# Auto-updating form in MVC without refreshing all the page

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-5, auto-update

I want to perform an Auto-update of a part of a view. In particular I want to update the `<div id="currentTemp">`.
What is the best way to perform that. I need to create a PartialView and update it?

This is the view:

```
@model Solution.Models.StateModel
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Temp";
 } 

<h2>StateDevice</h2>
<div class="row">
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CurrentTemperature, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div id="currentTemp" class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.CurrentTemperature)
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
}
</div>
```

This is the controller:

```
public ActionResult Device(int id)
    {
     // loading the stateModel from DataBase
     return View(stateModel);
    }
```

Comment: Bit unclear what your asking. Why do you have a form but no form controls? What are you expecting to submit?

Comment: To refresh a part of a page, you don't need a form. Use jquery `load` function on an action that will return a `PartialView`

Comment: Yes sorry just want to know  how to update a div in general

Comment: Who is the serial upvoter?

Comment: @ADreNaLiNe-DJ that is the best way?

Comment: The usual way. Take a look to this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21170271/5119765