# Load/Refresh only part of a page (View) using AJAX in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to achieve the same result as mentioned by the OP [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21170064/how-to-refresh-only-part-of-the-index-page-in-mvc-5/39607240#39607240) However when I try to render partial view by checking if it was an AJAX request in my Index action, its evaluating to false.

My Index View:

```
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Index", "Home",
    new AjaxOptions()
    {
        HttpMethod = "GET",
        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
        UpdateTargetId = "restaurantList"
    }))
{
    <input type="search" name="searchTerm" />
    <input type="submit" value="Search By Name" />
}

@Html.Partial("_Restaurant",Model)
```

My Partial View:

```
<div id="restaurantList" style="border:2px dotted red; padding-left:2em; margin-top:4px;">
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <div>
            <h4>@item.Name</h4>
            <div>@item.City, @item.Country</div>
            <div>@item.CountOfReviews</div>
            <hr />
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

My Index Action:

```
    public ActionResult Index(string searchTerm = null)
    {

        var model = ...//Building model object here

        if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            return PartialView("_Restaurant", model);
        }

        return View(model);
```

I would prefer not to dive into use of any jQuery or javascript as I am in the process of learning ASP.NET MVC, and would want to know why the approach I took is not working? The second answer by Dennis, in the post that I referenced also suggested similar approach.

Could someone kindly tell me what I am doing wrong?
Thanks

Comment: Have you included the relevant scripts to use `Ajax.BeginForm()` - `jquery-{version}.js` and `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js`? (you cannot make an ajax call without jquery or javascript)

Comment: Note also your `<div id="restaurantList" ... >` element should be in the main view, not the partial view.

Comment: @StephenMuecke
Yes I have. I have bundled all of the required libraries and added them in the BundleConfig.cs and referenced in the Shared Layout view.

Comment: If `if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())` is evaluating to `false` then it means your scripts are not loaded correctly and you making a normal submit

Comment: @StephenMuecke: I did change the `<div id="restaurantList"...>` element in the main view and still the same result.

Comment: @StephenMuecke : Thanks for pointing out that "the libraries not being loaded correctly" is the problem.
While creating a new bundle of all libraries I had missed `"~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js*"`. Got it working now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is just an example how you can load view from AJAX without page refresh, it may help you.

It send text value to controller by ajax call and load that value in other view which replace main view, if you don't want to replace main view then you can take other div instead same div to load content.

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{            
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public PartialViewResult TestAjax(string Name)
{
    ViewBag.Name = Name;
    return PartialView();
}
```

**Index.cshtml:**

```
<input type="button" id="btnSearch" class="btn btn-warning" style="height:35px;width:120px" value="Search"/> 
<label>Name:</label><input type="text" id="txtName" name="txtName" />


<script>
$('#btnSearch').click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("TestAjax", "Home")',
        data: { Name: $("#txtName").val() },
        type: 'POST',
        success: function (data) {
            $("#divContent").html(data);
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

**TestAjax.cshtml:**

```
@ViewBag.Name
```

Comment: Thanks Sandip. I will try out this approach too.

Answer (score 0):

As @StephenMuecke pointed out in his comments, the libraries not being loaded correctly was the problem. While creating a new bundle of all libraries and adding it in the `BundkeConfig.cs` I had missed `~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js*`. Got it working now.