# Open links from navigation bar into "content" area

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, material-design

I'm starting a new material design project in mvc.core and I have a question regarding navigation and links. If i click a link, it "takes over" the entire page instead of loading into the content area of the page. In oldschool HTML, I would use frames. But wat is the correct approach here? I have included a snippet:

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- Material Design Lite -->
    <script src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.indigo-pink.min.css">
    <!-- Material Design icon font -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
</head>
<body>
    <!-- The drawer is always open in large screens. The header is always shown,
    even in small screens. -->
    <div class="mdl-layout mdl-js-layout mdl-layout--fixed-drawer
            mdl-layout--fixed-header">
        <header class="mdl-layout__header">
            <div class="mdl-layout__header-row">
                <div class="mdl-layout-spacer"></div>
                <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--expandable
                  mdl-textfield--floating-label mdl-textfield--align-right">
                    <label class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--icon"
                           for="fixed-header-drawer-exp">
                        <i class="material-icons">search</i>
                    </label>
                    <div class="mdl-textfield__expandable-holder">
                        <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" name="sample"
                               id="fixed-header-drawer-exp">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
        <div class="mdl-layout__drawer">
            <span class="mdl-layout-title">Title</span>
            <nav class="mdl-navigation">
                <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="/Metering/Channels">Link</a>
                <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
                <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
                <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
            </nav>
        </div>
        <main class="mdl-layout__content">
            <div class="page-content"><!-- Your content goes here --></div>

        </main>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am not sure but I think that you are looking for Partial views => https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/partial?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Answer (score 1):

When you say it *"takes over" the entire page instead of loading into the content area* I guess you are talking about the browser window navigating away to a new page/refresh the same page.

If that is the case then consider using Ajax method and partial views. Which would update specific regions on the page. [Check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21170064/how-to-refresh-only-part-of-the-index-page-in-mvc-5)

Comment: Ok there is no way to use the target attribute in link for this? Using AJAX for this seems overly complicated just for opening a link in a different area - but perhaps this has shifted since i last delt with HTML (not my usual thing)

Comment: The target attribute is used for opening a new window. That is exactly what you are trying to avoid. Also if you write a generic function for Ajax calls with jQuery and then use that for various sections of the page then it would not be complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. It turns out you have to use Layouts - a feature of .NET Core MVC which directly supports what i want to do.